# Handling List in dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am finding trouble in calculating the profits generated by each company.
Ex:Consider the following dataset

```
Production company  Profits
A                    35000
c(B,C)               15000
D                   750000
c(E,F,G)            100000
```

I need to devise a way so that the profits earned are divided equally amongst each company. The output expected:

```
Production company  Profits
A                     35000
B                      7500
C                      7500
D                    750000
E                     33333
F                     33333
G                     33333
```

Can anyone please help me in achieving this in R? The production_company is a list so unlisting the column does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned your data structure, I am assuming its a data frame where columns are structured as a list. If this is the case you may try this.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

**Toy example**:-

```
df <- data.frame(val = c(1000, 7600, 2000))
df$pc <- list("A",c("B","C"), "D")
```

**Solution**:-

Taking the input dataset, use `lengths` (not to be confused with length) function to determine the number of items enclosed in that row of the desired column. Divide the values column with the number of items returned (In this case 7600 is divided by 2), since its a vectorized operation, it will be done for each of the rows.
select the desired columns as your final outcome.

```
df %>% 
    mutate(newval = val/lengths(.$pc)) %>% 
    unnest(pc)%>% 
    select(pc, newval)
```

**Output**:

```
  #    pc newval
  #  1  A   1000
  #  2  B   3800
  #  3  C   3800
  #  4  D   2000
```